# Flutter: Clip the content of column without shrinking the children

Tags: flutter, dart, widget

I have a card widget in which I have a row with CircleAvatar and a column as a child.
The height of the card reduces based on scrolling. I want the column to clip the content if they don't fit inside the card. I only want to show the name when the card is at its minimum height.

[image: Video]

I haved tried wrapping column with ClipRect, but it shows bottom overflow error.

Comment: share the code that u used?

Comment: If you add the code snippet to your question, you will more likely get a good answer.

Answer (score 1):

You can use SliverAppBar Widget for to achieve the mentioned behavior.

check the examples
[sample1](https://blog.logrocket.com/how-to-add-sliverappbar-to-your-flutter-app/)
[sample2](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/flutter-silverappbar-widget/)

Comment: But how do I add a card in sliver app bar? There is no child property in it.

Comment: Use slivers - https://docs.flutter.dev/ui/scrolling/slivers